# SQL - Invalid Column name in self created column

Tags: sql, string, datetime

Why SQL return an Error: "Invalid column name 'S_DATE'."

```
SELECT [FITTER]
      ,[STARTDATE]
      ,[S_DATE] = LEFT([STARTDATE], 11)


  FROM [DM_Fleetwave].[all_timesheets]
  WHERE cast([S_DATE] as datetime) >= dateadd(mm, -1, getdate())
```

I need to make a date cast cause original field ( STARTDATE) has string format. That’s why I created new column with date only.

Below is a how result looks like with out cast conditional:

```
FITTER               STARTDATE                    S_DATA
Mekker Sjelland      01/11/2019 00:00:00          01/11/2019
```

Comment: tag appropriate database name.

Comment: You are trying to cast S_Date but your column is S_Data. Typo

Comment: You can't use the alias from the `select` clause in your `where` clause. Also, why do you store dates as strings? Store dates as dates. One last thing, you're alias is `S_Data` and the where clause you're referring to `S_Date`.

Comment: S_Data / S_date - that was wrong spelling only here. I am not admin of data base - have only read only access. That is why i am asking.

Answer (score 0):

column_alias can be used in an ORDER BY clause, but it cannot be used in a WHERE, GROUP BY, or HAVING clause. Please try this below option-

You can see some ref [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/compact/sql-server-compact-4.0/ms173451(v=sql.110)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

```
SELECT [FITTER]
  ,[STARTDATE]
  ,[S_DATA] = LEFT([STARTDATE], 11)
FROM [DM_Fleetwave].[all_timesheets]
WHERE cast(LEFT([STARTDATE], 11) as datetime) >= dateadd(mm, -1, getdate())
-- Please make sure your first 11 character from STARTDATE column is always return a string that can be converted to a datetime type
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like SQL Server.  If so, you can define the column alias using `APPLY` in the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT t.FITTER, t.STARTDATE, v.S_DATE
FROM [DM_Fleetwave].[all_timesheets] t CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (LEFT([STARTDATE], 11))) v(S_Date)
WHERE CAST(v.S_DATE as datetime) >= DATEADD(MONTH, -1, getdate());
```

Alternative solutions are:

- Repeat the expression in the `WHERE`.
- Use a subquery to define the column.
- Use a CTE to define the column.